# Add and remove separators to urls by javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

I have links on page and want mask them. I want, 
that at `onLoad` all points in urls (which are in href) will be replaced with something like `"|"`,

so instead of

`<a href="http://www.example.com">link</a>`

there is somehting like

`<a href="http://www"|"example"|"com">link</a>`.

Then, at `onClick` replacements should be reversed to make links working again.

Need help to get this code to work:

```js
 function mask() {
     var str = document.getElementByName("a");
     var x = str.attributes.href.value.replace('.', '"|"');
     document.getElementsByTagName("a").attributes.href.value = x;
}

function unmask(){
     var str = document.getElementByName("a");
     var x = str.attributes.href.value.replace('"|"', '.');
     document.getElementsByTagName("a").attributes.href.value = x;

}
```

```html
<body onLoad="mask()">

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="unmask()">link</a>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`getElementsByTagName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getelementsbytagname.asp) method:

```js
function mask() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].attributes.href.value = a[i].attributes.href.value.replace(/\./g, '"|"');
  }
}

function unmask() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].attributes.href.value = a[i].attributes.href.value.replace(/"\|"/g, '.');
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="mask()">
  <a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="unmask()">link</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Why an `onError` trigering doesn't work? Like `<img src="non-existing-image.gif" onerror="unmask()"/>`

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in your code:

1. `document.getElementByName("a")` is not valid
2. `str.attributes.href.value` is not valid
3. You need to go global replace to replace all the `.` with `|` and vice-versa.

```js
function mask() {
     var str = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     var x = str.href.replace(/\./g, '"|"');
     str.href = x;
}

function unmask(){
     var str = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
     var x = str.href.value.replace(/"|"/g, '.');
     str.href = x;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="mask()">

<a href="http://www.example.com" onclick="unmask()">link</a>

</body>
```

Comment: unmasking doesn't work. you have an issue in unmasking regex - non-escaped pipe, i think